# I accidentally declined when Windows asked me if I should allow a gaming server program internet access. How to undo this?

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I accidentally declined when Windows asked me if I should allow a gaming server program internet access. How to undo this?

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: open advanced firewall setting  "C:\Windows\system32\WF.msc"  and change the setting to allow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Control Panel> Windows Firewall> Allow an App or Feature through Windows Firewall.

[image]

The you will see this page after clicking "Allow an App or Feature through Windows Firewall" on left side.

[image]

Click Change Settings button and see if it is the list and enable it, if not use the "Allow Another App..." button. Use Browse button to navigate to the program folder for the app you wish to allow, then highlight the app executable and hit OPEN to add it to the allowed list.